# Python: Convert JSON from df column into individual df columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have an excel file that looks something like this:

| Header1 | Header2 | Header3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | [{"key1":"123","key2":"Value1"},{"key1":"123","key2":"Value2"}, {"key1":"123","key2":"Value3"}] |
| data | data | [{"key1":"123","key2":"Value1"},{"key1":"123","key2":"Value2"}, {"key1":"123","key2":"Value3"}] |

Header3 contains JSON strings that look like this

```
[
{"key1":"123","key2":"Value1"},
{"key1":"123","key2":"Value2"}, 
{"key1":"123","key2":"Value3"}
]
```

I would like to parse the JSON Header3 column and for each key create a column with the name of the key appended with the value of key2, the keys are always the same throughout the file.

The end data frame should look something like this:

| Header1 | Header2 | Key1.Value1 | Key2.Value1 | Key1.Value2 | Key2.Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | 123 | Value1 | 123 | Value2 |
| data | data | 123 | Value1 | 123 | Value2 |

Actual example:

| Company | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| Amazon | [{"charge1":"500", "charge2":"200","card":"Visa"},{"charge1":"234", "charge2":"654","card":"Amex"} |
| Apple | [{"charge1":"689", "charge2":"433","card":"Visa"},{"charge1":"25434", "charge2":"6554644","card":"Amex"}] |

Needs to become:

| Company | charge1.Visa | charge2.Visa | card.Visa | charge1.AMEX | charge2.AMEX | card.AMEX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amazon | 500 | 200 | Visa | 234 | 654 | Amex |
| Apple | 689 | 433 | Visa | 25434 | 6554644 | Amex |

Before getting into fancy stuff I tried to at least normalize the data, but I'm returned with an empty series.

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
pd.json_normalize(df.JSON)

Output:
0
1
2
3
4
5
...
188 rows x 0 columns
```

Comment: For you actual example, the last object in in each JSON array doesn't have a card type. Do you want to drop it?

Comment: Sorry, the table was not displaying properly, so I made a change and inadvertently removed the card type. I will fix the example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't normalize it because it's loaded as string from Excel. Try this:

```py
import json

s = df["JSON"].apply(json.loads).explode()
tmp = (
    pd.DataFrame(s.to_list(), index=s.index)
    .set_index("card", append=True)
    .unstack()
)
tmp.columns = [".".join(col) for col in tmp.columns]

pd.concat([df[["Company"]], tmp], axis=1)
```

The `card.*` columns look kinda weird. If you know what column you are referring to, you already know its value so why include it in the output dataframe?

Comment: You're right, repeating the card type column is redundant, I was planning on dropping the columns after expanding the JSON. Does it make any difference if the numbers inside the JSON are floats? I'm getting a 
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not float on the first line

Comment: One of your rows contains invalid JSON so `json.loads` doesn't work